# How can I send an image from java socket Server to a navigator wihtout being corrupted?

Tags: java, serversocket, navigator, dataoutputstream

I am trying to code a java socket server to send an image from this server to the navigator(client side). But when I send the image the file seen to be corrupted (display the image with symbols).

```
                DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(connectS.getOutputStream());
                String file="image.jpg";
                File filename = new File(file);
                FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(filename);  
                //dout.writeUTF(file);
                System.out.println("Sending image...");
                int size=(int) filename.length();
                byte[] readData = new byte[size]; 
                fin.read(readData);
                dout.writeInt(size);
                dout.flush();
                dout.write(readData,0,size);
                /*for(int i=0;i<readData.length;i++) {
                     dout.write(readData, 0, i);
                }*/
                dout.flush();
```

Here is how I start the program

```
    ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(8080);
    Socket connectS=ss.accept();
    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectS.getInputStream()));
```

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Instead of DataOutputStream try using the OutputStream directly to write your file. DataOutputStream writes formatted binary data while OutputsStream writes the raw data.

Comment: I changed to OutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(connectS...) but it doesn't change anything. I can't change the second DataOutputStream whithout having an error.

Comment: Why are you sending the size word? Why aren't you sending any HTTP headers?

Comment: @Thecarisma `DataOutputStream` doesn't change what is written. Your suggestion makes no difference, or sense.

Comment: Oh my bad, I read the question wrong

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem.
First, remove dout.readInt();
Then, open microsoft edge;(mozilla shows the image but there seems to be an encoding issue,that's my opinion,maybe not the true);

Comment: First and only, remove `dout.writeInt()`. Nothing else required.